# Automatic Add class and remove it when menu is close or body click to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good Morning Honestly Speaking i dont know how to use js properly im starting lo learn from it from school. The code below once you click the menu with the class `menuToggle` the `modal-backdrop` adds up.  What i want to accomplish is after clicking or closing the menu again the class modal-backdrop will be remove as well.

the code below just ads up the modal-backdrop div and automatic remove after 10sec or more.

```
$("a.menuToggle").click(function() {
  var bd = $('<div class="modal-backdrop"></div>');
  bd.appendTo(document.body);
  setTimeout(function() {
    bd.remove();
  }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: add the html, but I'll provide an example anyways for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
   $("a.menuToggle").click(function() {
        if($('.modal-backdrop').length) {
            $(this).removeClass('.modal-backdrop');
        } else {
            var bd = $('<div class="modal-backdrop"></div>');
            bd.appendTo(document.body);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, you could use the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) `toggle()` method to toggle the classes removing `opacity` or `z-index` to "hide" the modal.

You could also do it in JS when you create the popup modal before appending it to the interface just set an event listener to remove itself when clicked.

```js
init=()=>{
 //SELECT & BIND (CLICK) EVENT
 document.querySelector('login').addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.init);
}
modal={
 overlay:{
  init:()=>{
   //CREATE OVERLAY 
   var overlay = document.createElement('overlay');
   //SET (CLICK) EVENT TO REMOVE ITSLEF
   overlay.addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.remove);
   //APPEND TO INTERFACE
   document.body.appendChild(overlay);
  },
  remove:(e)=>{
   //REMOVE ITSELF
   e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
  }  
 }
}

//ON DOCUMENT LOAD RUN INIT
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);
```

```css
html{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
html *{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 
/*  DISABLE USER SELECT */
 -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
body{
 z-index: 100;
 
 margin: 0 !important;
 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center; 
 
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#41a3ff,#0273D4);
}
login{
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  padding: .25em 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #0273D4;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0273D4;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
login:hover{
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
  /* background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.31); */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
}
login:active{
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
}
overlay{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<body>
 <login>click me</login>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect youre so awesome! and i just want to ask about this "just set an event listener to remove itself when clicked." how can i add another function once click it will click another toggle class at the same time  '$(function() {
        $("#welcomeDivs").click(function() {
            $(".parela").toggleClass('myClass');
        });
    });'

Comment: @technobisuit sorry for delay been out of the office today, from the code you posted in the above comment it looks like your selecting the id `#welcomeDivs` and setting an event listener to select a tag(s) by class `.parela` and then toggling the class on and off, which look good to me.

Comment: All you would have to do is set the event listener in your `init` function or whichever function creates the element(s) your binding that `click` event to.